# Serving localhost rails application externally https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, https, webserver

I am currently running a rails application on my local machine as the backend api for a hobby web application (have too many sql rows and dont want to pay for it).

I already figured out how to forward my port and access the api through http://[myexternalipaddress]:8080/api/etc.... from the external internet.

This is working fine, but i want to be able to serve this end point through https instead so my users dont get security warnings. I did some research, but I am confused what I need to do next. Is the https serving done via my rails configuration, or some other method?

here is the command I use to start my rails server:

```
rails s --binding=0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and expose your local server

on `mac` you can install it with `brew`

```
$ brew cask install ngrok
$ ngrok http 3000
```

this will give you url like `https://xxyyzz.ngrok.io` to access it publicly